# Proof of Comparability Theorem for well-ordered sets using transfinite recursion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, well-orders

I am reading through Halmos's "Naive Set Theory". In Section 18, Halmos uses transfite recursion to prove the Comparability Thereom for well-ordered sets:

> The assertion is that if $\langle X, \leqslant_X \rangle$ and $\langle Y, \leqslant_Y \rangle$ are well ordered sets, then either $X$ and $Y$ are similar, or one of them is similar to an initial segment of the other.

> We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty well ordered sets such that neither is similar to an initial segment of the other; we proceed to prove that under these circumstances $X$ must be similar to $Y$. Suppose that $a \in X$ and that $t$ is a sequence of type $a$ in $Y$; in other words $t$ is a function from $s(a)$ into $Y$. Let $f(t)$ be the least of the proper upper bounds of the range of $t$ in $Y$, if there are any; in the contrary case, let $f(t)$ be the least element of $Y$. In the terminology of the transfinite recursion theorem, the function $f$ thereby determined is a sequence function of type $X$ in $Y$. Let $U$ be the function that the transfinite recursion theorem associates with this situation. An easy argument (by transfinite induction) shows that, for each $a \in X$, the function $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$. This implies $U$ is a similarity, and the proof is complete.

I think I understand the proof up until this step:

> An easy argument (by transfinite induction) shows that, for each $a
>   \in X$, the function $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-
> one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$.
> This implies $U$ is a similarity, and the proof is complete.

I can't seem to get my head around this "easy transfinite induction". I think I get what I am meant to do. Let $S$ be the set such that $a \in S$ if and only if there exists a bijection between $s(a)$ and $s(U(a))$. We need to prove that if $s(b) \subseteq S$, then $b \in S$. This would imply that $S = X$ by the transfinite induction principle. I assume I need to construct a bijection from $s(b)$ to $s(U(b))$ using the bijections for each $a < b$, but I am unsure of how to proceed with this.

Note that Halmos has not introduced the concept of ordinal numbers at this point in the book, only well-ordered sets. As a result, I'd appreciate any help which avoids the use of "ordinal terminology". There has been a [question on the site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001032/prove-the-comparability-theorem-for-well-ordered-sets-using-transfinite-inductio) that has asked about this before but I couldn't really make sense of the answers and comments.

EDIT: At the suggestion of the comments I decided to work through the following example:

$$
X = a > b > c > d \\
Y = e > f > g > h
$$

Then starting at $a$ we have

$$
U(a) = e \\
U(b) = f \\
U(c) = g \\
U(d) = h \\ 
$$

I kind of understand how the proof works in these kind of instances as each element has an immediate predecessor. In this case, we can use the following argument. Any $x \in X$ has an immediate predecessor, say $x^{\prime}$ (apart from base case that is easy). So we must have $s(x) - \{x^{\prime}\} = s(x^{\prime})$. We construct an isomorphism by taking the isomorphism we know exists from $s(x^{\prime})$ to $s(U(x^{\prime}))$ and simply add the pair $(x^{\prime}, U(x^{\prime}))$.

However, I don't really understand what to do when an element of $X$ does not have an immediate predecessor. For example consider the set of positive integers $X$, where every odd is greater than every even. Then consider the set $Y$ of positive integers where every even is greater than every odd. In both sets order the odds with respect to each other as normal, and the evens with respect to each other as normal. So we have

$$
X = 2 < 4 < 6 < \dots < 1000< 1002 < \dots < 1 < 3 < \dots \\
Y = 1 < 3 < 5 < \dots < 1001 < 1003 < \dots < 2 < 4 < \dots 
$$

How does transfinite recursion deal with the case where $b = 1$ as $1$ has no immediate predecessor?

EDIT:

I think I understand the proof now. Either:

i) $b$ has an immediate predecessor $c$ in $s(b)$. In which case, all $a \in s(b) - \{c\}$ are mapped one-to-one into $U|_{s(c)}$ and thus $U|_{s(b)}$. By definition of $U$, $U(c) < U(b)$ and $U(c) > U(a)$ for all $a \in  s(b) - \{c\}$, thus $U(c) \in s(U(b)$ and $U(c) \neq U(a)$ for all $a \in s(c)$. Hence $U|_{s(b)}$ is an injection into $s(U(b))$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $U|_{s(b)}$ is not onto. Then there exists some $y$ such that $U(c) < y < U(b)$. However, then $U(b)$ would not be the least upper bound of $U|_{s(b)}$, thus we have a contradiction and no such $y$ can exist. So $U|_{s(b)}$ must map onto $s(U(b))$. Hence $U|_{s(b)}$ is a surjection and an injection and thus a bijection onto $s(U(b))$ as desired.

ii) $b$ has no immediate predecessor in $s(b)$. Then for every $a \in s(b)$ there exists another $c \in s(b)$ such that $a \in s(c)$. Observe that we can write $U|_{s(b)}$ as $\bigcup_{a \in s(b)}U|_{s(a)}$, and hence $U|_{s(b)}$ is an injection. Next we prove that $s(U(b))$ is in the range of $U|_{s(b)}$. For the sake of contradiction assume there is $y \in s(U(b))$ such that $y$ is not in the range of $U|_{s(b)}$. Then there are three cases that can occur:

1. $y$ is the least element in $s(U(b))$. Let $x$ be the least element in $X$. By definition of $U$ we must have $U(x) = y$. Hence $y$ is in the range of $U|_{s(b)}$ for all $b \neq x$. Since $U|_{s(x)} = \{\}$, this implies case (1) cant occur.
2. There are elements $a$ and $c$ in the range of $U|_{s(b)}$ such that $a < y < c$. However this would imply $y$ is not in the range of $U|_{s(c)}$, a contradiction. Thus case (2) can't occur.
3. $a < y$ for  all $a \in s(U(b))$. In this case $U(b)$ is not the least upper bound of $U|_{s(b)}$, a contradiction by the definition of $U$. Thus case (3) can't occur.

So in all cases, we have a contradiction and thus $s(U(b))$ must lie in the range of $U|_{s(b)}$. Lastly we observe that the range of $U|_{s(b)}$ lies in $s(U(b))$. If it didn't then $U(b)$ would not be an upper bound for $U|_{s(b)}$. Thus we conclude that $U|_{s(b)}$ is a surjection onto $s(U(b))$. Thus as $U|_{(s(b)}$ is surjective and injective, it is bijection onto $s(U(b))$ as desired.

Thus for both cases $(i)$ and $(ii)$ the result holds and we are done.

EDIT: This is answer to a question in the comments below posed by jsmith:

> How does the definition of U imply that U(c) < U(b)

By definition $U(a) = f(U^{a})$ so either:

$\text{range}(U^{a}) < U(a)$ or $f(U^{a})$ is the least element of $Y$. In the first case, the result follows trivially. We can show that the second case causes a contradiction. More specifically, if the second case occurs then the range of $U^{a}$ has no upper bound and must contain a maximal element of $Y$. As a result, $Y$ must be similar to an initial segment of $X$, which we assumed was not the case. I will leave the details for you to work out but I hope that answers your question!

Comment: It sounds like you are completely misunderstanding the claim being made here.  What is being claimed is that for all $a\in X$, the restricted function $U|_{s(a)}$ is a bijection from $s(a)$ to $s(U(a))$.  This statement is to be proved by induction on $a$.

Comment: If you have no idea what is going on here I would strongly recommend actually writing out an example.  Let $X$ and $Y$ each have $4$ elements, say, and write out what the function $U$ ends up being using the recursive definition and why the claim is true.

Comment: I have a question. Does similarity mean an order isomorphism?

Comment: @Hermis14 Yes, it means order isomorphism I think (A bijection which preserves the order of elements)

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I understand finite examples, as far as I can see, transfinite induction is the same as regular induction in this case. I have updated the question with the kind of example I am struggling with

Comment: I have a lot of questions, sorry. I guess I'll start with....how does the definition of U imply that U(c) < U(b)?

Comment: @jsmith I have left an edit in the original question with an answer to your question. I think my reasoning is correct, but feel to let me know if you think I have made a mistake!

Comment: Is there any place where the fact that X cannot be similar to an initial segment of Y is used?

Comment: Hi @NickBishop: Regarding your edit in which you proved "definition of U implies U(c) < U(b)", could you please tell me what do you mean by saying "range($U^a) \lt U(a)$" ? why do you compare a set of values ( i.e. range($U^a$)) with a value (i.e. U(a)) ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let $(X_1,\le_1), (X_2,\le_2)$ be any well-orderings. If they are similar then call an order-isomorphism $f:X_1\to X_2$ a similarity.

(1).Lemma. The only similarity  from a well-ordering from itself to itself is the identity function.

(2).Lemma. There is at most one similarity  $f:X_1\to X_2$.

(3). Lemma. No well-ordering is  similar to an initial segment of itself.

For $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $a\in X_i$ let pred$_i(a)=\{b: b<_i a\}.$ ("Pred" for "predecessors").

For $x\in X_1$ let $x\in X_1^*$ iff pred$_1(x)$ is similar to an initial segment of $X_2.$ For $x\in X_2$ let $x\in X_2^*$ iff pred$_2(x)$ is similar to an initial segment of $X_1$. The sets $X_1^*,X_2^*$ exist by the Axiom Schema of Comprehension.

If y$<_2y'$ then pred$_2(y)$ is an initial segment of pred$_2(y')$ so by (3), no pred$_1(x)$ can be similar to both pred$_2(y)$ and pred$_2(y').$ So for each $x\in X_1^*$ there is a unique $U(x)\in X_2$ such that pred$_1(x)$ is similar to pred$_2(U(x))$. And by (2), if $x\in X_1^*$ there is a unique similarity $f_x:$pred$_1(x)\to $ pred$_2(U(x)).$

Analogously, if $y\in X_2^*$ then there is a unique $V(y)\in X_1$ such that pred$_2(y)$ is similar to pred$_1(V(y)),$ and there is a unique similarity $g_y:\text{pred}_2(y)\to \text{ pred}_1(V(y)).$

The Axiom Schema of Replacement implies existence of the functions $U=\{(x,U(x)):x\in X_1^*\}$ and $V=\{(y,V(y)):y\in X_2^*\}.$

We can show by elementary considerations, without Recursion, that exactly one of the following holds:

(i)... $X_1^*=X_1$  and $X_2^*=X_2$ and $U:X_1\to X_2$ is a similarity.

(ii)...$X_1^*$ is an initial segment of $X_1$ and $X_2^*=X_2$ and $V:X_2\to X_1^*$ is a similarity.

(iii). $X_2^*$ is an initial segment of $X_2$ and $X_1^*=X_1$ and $U:X_1\to X_2^*$ is a similarity.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as, even though I was looking for a proof using transfinite recursion, this response provides a nice alternative method. In fact, Halmos discusses this alternative proof in his book, but not in much detail. Hopefully my edits to the main question will help anyone looking for a proof involving transfinite recursion.

Comment: How do you show that one of (i), (ii), or (iii) must hold?

Answer (score 1):

A possible formulation of the "easy transfinite induction":

Write
$$S=\{a \in X: \exists b \in Y\,(U^a \text{ maps } s(a)\text{ one-to-one onto } s(b))\,\}$$

Now suppose $s(x) \subset S$, and let $x^\prime$ be the immediate predecessor of $x$, so $U^{x^\prime}$ maps $s(x^\prime)$ one-to-one onto $s(y^\prime)$, where $y^\prime \in Y$ and it's immediate successor in $Y$ is $y$. Note also that $s(x) \in S$ means that $U^{x^\prime}$ is a *similarity* between $s(x^\prime)$ and $s(y^\prime)$.

we know that the domain of $U^x$ is $s(x^\prime) \cup \{x^\prime\}= s(x)$, on the other hand:

$U^x=U^{x^\prime} \cup U|\{x^\prime\}$ ,

and $U|\{x^\prime\}$ is determined by the range of $U^{x^\prime}$, i.e. $s(y^\prime)$, in particular,

$$U(x^\prime)=y \text{ (the immediate successor of $y^\prime$)}$$

as far as $Y$ is not yet exhausted, which cannot be the case, for then $Y$ would be similar to an initial segment of $X$.

The range of $U^x$ is then $s(y^\prime) \cup \{y^\prime\} =s(y)$.

so $U^x$ maps $s(x)$ one-to-one onto $s(y)$, we have $x \in S$.

Since $X$ is well-ordered and $\forall x \in S (s(x) \subset S \to x \in S)$ as shown above, the principle of transfinite induction yields:

$$S=X$$

Therefore $U$ is a similarity with $X$ as its domain, since $X$ is not similar to any of the initial segments of $Y$, $U$ must map $X$ one-to-one onto $Y$.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but why can we assume that an immediate predecessor exists?

Comment: @NickBishop If your concern is about the base case you may want to revisit p.67 of _Naive Set Theory_, paragraph starting with ‘The second difference between…’ which explains why base case is not needed in such an induction.  But I have to admit that if $x$ happens to be $\omega$ the proof will need some reformulation, but basically the line of thought remains the same.